# Cannot let go of an object when in another object's collider

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I have some fairly simple code that allows me to grab, move, and let go of objects (in this case, the "LoopCubes" are the only things I want to be able to pick up:

```
public void grab(object sender, ClickedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((objectTouching != null) && objectTouching.CompareTag("LoopCube") == true)
    {
        objectTouching.gameObject.transform.SetParent(gameObject.transform);
    }
}

//Letting go of grip
public void releaseGrab(object sender, ClickedEventArgs e)
{
    if (objectTouching != null)
    {
        objectTouching.gameObject.transform.parent = null;
    }
}
```

This works as intended. However, a problem arises when I want to let go of the cube when the controller/cube are within a box collider (marked as a trigger). I can't let go and the cube becomes 'stuck' to the controller. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does that "stuck" mean ? You assign `null` but you still can reference one, or you expect immediate release of memory once `null` is assigned ?

Comment: By 'stuck' I mean I cannot let go of the cube, even by pressing and releasing the grip. I'm afraid I don't understand your second question.

Comment: Well, it's hard to deduct from the code provided what's happening there. You may have temp variables that are still pointing to the cube, and resetting to `null` parent has not any effect on them, hence you continue using them like before. Just an example of what may happen.

Comment: Ah, I understand. @Fredrik mentioned something similar below, and I think that sounds like what's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I can't see your code I'm going to make some assumptions.
This is what I'm guessing is happening:

1. Enter a trigger and set it to `objectTouching`
2. Grab `objectTouching` & move around
3. Enter another trigger, which sets `objectTouching` to something else, still having the previous objectTouching grabbed
4. Release, which tries to release the current objectTouching, which is the last trigger you entered - not the grabbed object.

Comment: That seems very plausible! Can you think of a way around this?

Comment: Show me the grabbing code! What i'd do is to simply reference the grabbed object instead of the last touched object when releasing.

Comment: In terms of grabbing itself, that's all there is. The other code I have is for entering/exiting the trigger on the controller. I'll edit my question to include that code.

Comment: Oh sorry, I now see that you ARE showing the grabbing code. After your `SetParent(transform)` you should save _that_ object, `currentHeldObject = objectTouching` where currentHeldObject is a class GameObject variable

Comment: Yes, sorry - I wrote too hasty :)

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that a shot and mark your answer as successful if it works out.

Comment: ...and it worked! Much appreciated. That's saved me a lot of headache :)